# PowerShell & XML: cannot extract InnerText value if text is preceded by a dot

Tags: xml, powershell-5.0

Sample XML file:

```
<input>
    <filePattern>
        <midfix>.bof-fix</midfix>
        <format>raw</format>
    </filePattern>
</input>
```

If I try to extract the text from "format" element, the following script works OK:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ps_scripts\configs\*" -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
    $xml_file = $_
    $curr_dir = $xml_file
    $content = [xml](Get-Content $curr_dir)
    $nodes = $content.SelectNodes("//input")
    
    foreach ($node in $nodes) {
        $format = $node.SelectNodes('filePattern/format').InnerText
        $format
        
    }        
}
```

The output is:

```
raw
```

But if I modify the above script by replacing the 2 lines in foreach loop with this:

```
$midfix = $content.SelectNodes('filePattern/midfix').InnerText 
$midfix
```

then there is no output at all. Expected output:

```
.bof-fix
```

Apparently this is because of the leading dot (.) in the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's going to work with PS 5.0, but try it this way and see if it works:

```
$nodes = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//midfix")
foreach ($node in $nodes) {
        $format = $node.InnerText
         $format        
    }
```

Edit:
To refelct comment below:
change

```
$nodes = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//midfix")
```

to

```
$nodes = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//input//midfix")
```

Comment: yeah it works, thanks. A slight problem is that this modification will check all "midfix" elements - and I need to check only those "midfix" elements that are children of "input" element.